# Select being skipped over

Tags: html, html-select, selecteditem, selected

Ok so I'm having a really weird issue here that just started acting up. I have an age selector made that allows a minimum age to be set to 18 years old then have 18-68. For some reason its being printed out on Firefox as 18 as the auto selected option. If I take out the 18 then it goes back to auto selecting minimum age. Can anyone give me a hand on understanding what I'm doing wrong?

```
<select name="age_min_search_html" id="Age_min_search_html" data-mini="true">
  <option value="18" selected="selected">Minimum Age</option>
  <option value="18" >18</option>
  <option value="19" >19</option>
  <option value="20" >20</option>
  <option value="21" >21</option>
  <option value="22" >22</option>
  <option value="23" >23</option>
  <option value="24" >24</option>
  <option value="25" >25</option>
  <option value="26" >26</option>
  <option value="27" >27</option>
  <option value="28" >28</option>
  <option value="29" >29</option>
  <option value="30" >30</option>
  <option value="31" >31</option>
  <option value="32" >32</option>
  <option value="33" >33</option>
  <option value="34" >34</option>
  <option value="35" >35</option>
  <option value="36" >36</option>
  <option value="37" >37</option>
  <option value="38" >38</option>
  <option value="39" >39</option>
  <option value="40" >40</option>
  <option value="41" >41</option>
  <option value="42" >42</option>
  <option value="43" >43</option>
  <option value="44" >44</option>
  <option value="45" >45</option>
  <option value="46" >46</option>
  <option value="47" >47</option>
  <option value="48" >48</option>
  <option value="49" >49</option>
  <option value="50" >50</option>
  <option value="51" >51</option>
  <option value="52" >52</option>
  <option value="53" >53</option>
  <option value="54" >54</option>
  <option value="55" >55</option>
  <option value="56" >56</option>
  <option value="57" >57</option>
  <option value="58" >58</option>
  <option value="59" >59</option>
  <option value="60" >60</option>
  <option value="61" >61</option>
  <option value="62" >62</option>
  <option value="63" >63</option>
  <option value="64" >64</option>
  <option value="65" >65</option>
  <option value="66" >66</option>
  <option value="67" >67</option>
  <option value="68" >68</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You souldn't have two options with same **value**.change value of `Minimum Age` to another value

Comment: i see what you're saying but I have other fields that have default values that a user would be able to just click the search button, so for what I'm going for I need it. Works fine in Chrome and IE, Firefox is being the issue.